# Browserify import not from node_modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, phoenix-framework

I'm using `browserify` to handle ES6 `import`, and I'm trying to import `phoenix.js` from `deps/phoenix`. I was trying to add `phoenix` to my `package.json`:

`"phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix"`

but `browserify` seems to look for modules only in `node_modules` if not importing local files.

One solution is to import `phoenix` as local file
`import { Socket } from '../../../deps/phoenix'`
but then path is relative so not the best solution.
Any thought or ideas?